# What is the flow of control?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am not understanding the flow of control since I am a newbie. In this code, after the component is rendered, useEffects get called. When the first useEffect is called, it is dispatching an action. So, after the action is dispatched, it should re-render the component because I am fetching the change in state from useSelector. Instead, it is executing the second useEffect. Similar is the case with the third useEffect, after it is triggered, it is changing the formData which is in useState. Instead of re-rendering, it is executing the 4th useEffect. Can anyone please help me understand the flow right from the start to the end?

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useRef} from "react";
import AdminLayout from "../../../hoc/adminLayout";
import {useFormik,FieldArray,FormikProvider} from "formik";
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {validation,formValues} from "./validationSchema";
import {getAdminArticle,updateArticle} from "../../../store/actions/articles_actions";
import {clearCurrentArticle} from "../../../store/actions/index";
import Loader from "../../../utils/loader";
import { 
    TextField, 
    Button, 
    Divider, 
    Chip,
    Paper,
    InputBase,
    IconButton,
    Select,
    MenuItem,
    FormControl,
    FormHelperText
} from '@material-ui/core';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import WYSIWYG from "../../../utils/forms/wysiwyg";


const EditArticle=(props)=>{
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    const notifications=useSelector((state)=>{
        return state.notifications;
    })
    const articles=useSelector((state)=>{
        return state.articles;
    })
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading]=useState(true); 
    const [editorBlur,setEditorBlur]=useState(false);
    const [formData,setFormData]=useState(formValues);
    const actorsValue=useRef("");

    /////edit/////
    const [editContent,setEditContent]=useState(null);
    ////edit////


    const formik=useFormik({
        enableReinitialize:true,
        initialValues:formData,
        validationSchema:validation,
        onSubmit:(values,{resetForm})=>{
        //console.log(values);
        setIsLoading(true);
        dispatch(updateArticle(values,props.match.params.id));
      
        }
    });

    const handleEditorState=(state)=>{
        formik.setFieldValue("content",state,true);  
              
    }

    const handleEditorBlur=(blur)=>{
        setEditorBlur(true);
    }
    const errorHelper=(formik,value)=>{
        return {
            error:formik.errors[value] && formik.touched[value]? true:false,
            helperText:formik.errors[value] && formik.touched[value]?formik.errors[value]:null
        }

    }

    
    ///////edit/////////
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("first");
        dispatch(getAdminArticle(props.match.params.id));

    },[dispatch,props.match.params])
    /////edit///////
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("second");
        
        
        // if(notifications && notifications.success){
        //     props.history.push("/dashboard/articles");
        // }
        // if(notifications && notifications.error){
            setIsLoading(false);

        // }


    },[notifications,props.history])



    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("third");
        if(articles && articles.current){
        setFormData(articles.current);
        setEditContent(articles.current.content);
        }
    },[articles])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("unmounted");
        return ()=>{
            dispatch(clearCurrentArticle());
        }
    },[dispatch])
   
     
        return <AdminLayout section="Add Article">
        {console.log("rendered")}
        {isLoading?<Loader />:<form className="mt-3 article_form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
        <TextField 
        style={{width:"100%"}}
        name="title"
        label="Enter a title"
        variant="outlined"
        {...formik.getFieldProps("title")}
        {...errorHelper(formik,"title")}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
        <WYSIWYG setEditorState={(state)=>{
            return handleEditorState(state)
        }}   setEditorBlur={(blur)=>{
            return handleEditorBlur(blur)
        }} 
        editContent={editContent}

        />
         {formik.errors.content && editorBlur?
            <FormHelperText error={true}>
            {formik.errors.content}
            </FormHelperText> :null}
        
        <TextField 
        type="hidden"
        name="content"
        {...formik.getFieldProps("content")}

        />
     </div>
        <div className="form-group">
        <TextField 
        style={{width:"100%"}}
        name="excerpt"
        label="Enter an excerpt"
        variant="outlined"
        {...formik.getFieldProps("excerpt")}
        {...errorHelper(formik,"excerpt")}
        multiline
        rows={4}
       />
        </div>
        <Divider className="mt-3 mb-3" />
        <h5>Movie Data and Score</h5>
        <div className="form-group">
        <TextField 
        style={{width:"100%"}}
        name="score"
        label="Enter an score"
        variant="outlined"
        {...formik.getFieldProps("score")}
        {...errorHelper(formik,"score")}
       />
        </div>
                  <FormikProvider value={formik}>
                    <h5>Add the Actors</h5>
                   <FieldArray name="actors"
                  render={
                  arrayhelpers=>(
                 <div>
                    <Paper className="actors_form">
                    <InputBase
                    className="input"
                    placeholder="Add actor name here" 
                    inputRef={actorsValue}
                    />
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>{
                        arrayhelpers.push(actorsValue.current.value);
                        actorsValue.current.value="";
                    }}>
                    <AddIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    </Paper>
                    {formik.errors.actors && formik.touched.actors?
                     <FormHelperText error={true}>
                     {formik.errors.actors}
                     </FormHelperText> :null}
                    <div className="chip_container">
                    {formik.values.actors.map((actor,index)=>{
                       return <div key={actor}>
                        <Chip label={`${actor}`} color="primary" onDelete={()=>{
                            return arrayhelpers.remove(index);
                        }}>
                       </Chip>
                        </div>
                    })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
           } 
         />
        </FormikProvider>

        <div className="form-group">
        <TextField 
        style={{width:"100%"}}
        name="score"
        label="Enter the Director"
        variant="outlined"
        {...formik.getFieldProps("director")}
        {...errorHelper(formik,"director")}
       />
        </div>
        <FormControl variant="outlined" >
            <h5>Select a Status</h5>
            <Select
            name="status"
            {...formik.getFieldProps("status")}
            error={formik.errors.status && formik.touched.status? true:false}
            > 
            <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>      
            <MenuItem value="draft">Draft</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="public">Public</MenuItem>          
            </Select>
            {formik.errors.status && formik.touched.status?
            <FormHelperText error={true}>
            {formik.errors.status}
            </FormHelperText> :null}
        </FormControl>
        <Divider className="mt-3 mb-3" />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" >
            Edit Article
        </Button>
        </form>
}          
</AdminLayout>    
}

export default EditArticle;
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: It seems your confusion lies in not understanding that all React hooks are called each and every render cycle, ***in the same order*** they are defined. In the case of hooks with dependencies, if a dependency has updated then the associated callback is invoked. If 2 separate `useEffect` hooks result in dependencies being updated in the same render cycle then they will trigger anything depending on them. Dispatching actions won't ever trigger a rerender. Updating state or props will.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dispatching an action will not cause re-render but using useSelector will cause it to re-render right? useSelector will check the change in the state and cause re-render. Can you please let me know if my understanding regarding useSelector is right or wrong?

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector The `useSelector` hook can trigger rerender.